# How to remove an element from the local storage by clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This function adds tasks in an array `myTasks` which is the value of a key `--TASKS`in a local storage.I want to remove a particular task by clicking on the cross button both from the front and back end.
    The `onClick[i]` should remove the item both from the front end as well as from the local storage .

```
function addTasks() {
    var j;
    var myTasks = [];
    //gets the stored tasks in the array
    myTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(session))[0].TASKS; 
    if ((myTasks.length) >= 1) {
      for ( j = 0; j < (myTasks.length); j++) {
        var ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var t = document.createTextNode(myTasks[j]);
        li.appendChild(t);
        document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);

        var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
        var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
        span.className = "close";
        span.appendChild(txt);
        li.appendChild(span);

        for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
          close[j].onclick = function () {
           var index= myTasks.indexOf(j);
            console.log(myTasks);
            var div = this.parentElement;
            //myTasks.splice(i,1);
            div.style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("myUL").value = "";

    }
  }
```

[image: The cross button should remove tasks from the local storage]
.

Comment: What did you try already? Also see: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to delete the session in localstorage and store the edited array again in session.

I assume that you have deleted the task from the array myTasks.

```
localStorage.remove(session);
localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(myTasks));
```